# Are the twentyish constants that have to fall in-between certain ranges to make conditions for live to exist necessary?

Tags: physical-constants, multiverse, fine-tuning

I have been listening to an audiobook about [what we cannot know](https://books.google.lt/books/about/What_We_Cannot_Know_Explorations_at_the.html?id=u2z8CQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (although I have heard about 20 constants somewhere before that, just can't recall where) and in chapter 9, author talks about twenty constants that have to be in certain ranges for life to exist ([fine-tuned universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_universe)) and then starts talking about [multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse).

I was able to find six of them in the same article about the [fine-tuned universe in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_universe), but not the others.

To me, confusion comes from the fact that our universe is made up of four fundamental forces and spacetime and that's it, there is nothing more than that, and these four forces should describe everything. So that would imply that fundamental forces and spacetime have to fall between some ranges and all the rest of the constants are just a result of that.

**Would four fundamental forces falling between certain ranges be enough to allow conditions for life? Or am I missing something?**

Comment: You forgot particles in your universe. And particles have certain properties, like mass, which we don't have an explanation for and must be measured.

You can find more about the constants here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_physical_constant

Comment: IMO, this really isn't a physics question. It's an overly broad hypothetical philosophic question based on extrapolation of a single data point (our universe). Anything anyone says it's an (unprovable) opinion of theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Umaxo, a universe containing four forces would be a pretty boring place because it would contain no particles. When you add in the particles we know about, you have to insert their masses, charges and spins into the Standard Model and doing so adds in a list of physical constants whose values we measure through experiment but which are not predicted by the model itself.